# gSOAP generate unicode support

Tags: xml, soap, gsoap

I'm trying to figure out how to tell the wsdl2h.exe header generator that comes with gSOAP not to use char* anywhere in the generated header.

For some critical types, we've created a custom definition in the typemap.dat However there must be a way to tell it to not use char* for anything in the generated code.

Usually the solution would be to edit the generated headerfile, but we are running wsdl2h then soapcpp2 dynamically on every build as the WSDL isn't finalized yet.

Does anyone know how to force the wsdl2h tool to only use wchar_t* and not char*

Answer (score 2):

just add the line below to your typemap.dat file:

```
xsd__string   = | wchar_t* | wchar_t*
```